# custom dialog only display a small white box

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I'm trying to display a custom Dialog. I replicated a class which perfectly works and used it for this dialog but it don't display anything but a little box in the middle of the screen.

I can't figure out what's wrong....

Dialog onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fleet_select_dialog, null);

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = (display.getWidth() );
        int height = (display.getHeight() );
        getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,(width/3)*2 );            
    }
```

xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/fleet_select_dialog">

    <EditText
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/edit_fence2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:textColor="@color/themeapp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_corner_white"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_fence2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@color/themeapp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerview" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:id="@+id/footerview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Confirm"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_view"
            android:textColor="@color/themeapp"
            android:textSize="24dip"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="20dip"
            android:paddingRight="8dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/waiting"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:id="@+id/textView16" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

the dialog is used like this:

```
fleetSelectDialog = new FleetSelectDialog(context);
                fleetSelectDialog.show();
```

what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidently deleted one important line:

```
this.setContentView(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the windowLayout of the dialog before you set the content view with the inflater.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your view directly from the Layout Inflater, you only need to use the name of your layout XML file and the ID of the layout in file.

Use the following code to set the layout of your AlertDialog

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout. fleet_select_dialog, null); 
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.show();
```

Comment: Thats only the case if he is using the Builder right? Otherwise he wil need to the set the layoutParams of the Dialog window in onCreate before he sets any content for that Dialog (i.e inflate his xml layout class)

Answer (score 0):

```
                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);                             
                            // hide to default title for Dialog    

                            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                                // inflate the layout dialog_layout.xml and set it
                                // as contentView
                                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customize_dialog, null, false);
                                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                                dialog.setContentView(view);
                                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
                                dialog.show();
```

Enjoy full code.

Cheers !

Comment: I have already used it and got my desired output with good performance.